# Moving to the only one next list item with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got navigation on my which looks like this:

```
<img id="leftButton" />
  <ul id="bullets">
    <li class="style"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
<img id="rightButton" />
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when you click on right or the left button, the class 'style' moves to the neareast sibling.
For example when I click on the #rightButton I want to move the style class from the first list item to the second one, and so on and so forth. 
I came into something like this:

```
$('#rightButton').click(function() {
    if  ($('#bullets li').hasClass('style')) {
        $('#bullets li').removeClass('style');
        $('#bullets li').next().addClass('style').
        }
});
```

With something like this, when you click on the #rightButton it correctly removes class "style" from the first list item, but adds that class to all the other ones.

Oh and sorry for this messed up code, I'm a begginer with jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are using does not target a single element in this case. `#bullets li` will return all 5 list items contained within the element with id `#bullets`. If you want to target the single `li` which is assigned the CSS class `active`, change your selector to `#bullets li.active`.

So, your code would become:

```
$('#rightButton').click(function() {
    $('#bullets li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
});
```

Note that you can chain your calls, and no need to test whether or not an element was returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#rightButton, #leftButton').on('click', function(e) {
    var cur = $('ul#bullets li.style'),
        next = cur.next('li'),
        prev = cur.prev('li');
    if (e.target.id == 'rightButton') {
        if (next.length == 1) {
            cur.removeClass('style');
            next.addClass('style');
        }
    } else if (e.target.id = 'leftButton') {
        if (prev.length == 1) {
            cur.removeClass('style');
            prev.addClass('style');
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/yKRga/17/)

Comment: Great that worked perfectly. But there's one little bug. When I go to the end of the list and click #rightButton one more time the class 'style' disappears from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using:

```
$('#rightButton').click(function() {
    $('#bullets li.style').removeClass('style').next().addClass('style');
});​
```